# Apache Nifi Transfrom json field to timestamp

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the json with unix-timestamp field. I like to extract year from it.

So, for example:

```
{"eventno": "event1",
"unixtimestamp": 1589379890}
```

Expected result:

```
{"eventno": "event1",
"unixtime": 2020}
```

I try to do this using JoltTransfromJSON and NiFi expression language, but my attempts failed. One of them:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "unixtime": "${unixtimestamp:multiply(1000):format('yyyy', 'GMT')}"
    }
  }
]
```

How can I transform it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GrigorySkvortsov

The Expression Language syntax should be:

`${attribute:expressionLanguage():functions()}`

If what you have above isn't just a typo retest after removing the } after unixtimestamp.

Unit Test outside of Jolt Transform with updateAttribute Processor to dial in the correct Expression Language chain.  Here is an example I made to test it:

[image]

Then the 4 values are:
[image: d]

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @steven-dfheinz , but it didn't solve my problem. I have the empty string from JoltTransfromJSON processor.

Comment: This means your expression chain is wrong.   When I am testing this kind of logic,  I create a separate test flow (GenerateFlowFIle->UpdateAttribute(1)->UpdateAttribute(2).  Create an attribute of the value you have in 1, then send that to another update attribute (2), and test various different combinations of Expression Language.

Comment: test2 -> ${input:multiply(1000):format('MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss') }
test2 = 05-13-2020 02:24:50

I think what you want is ${unixtimestamp:multiply(1000):format('yyyy'') }

Comment: I confirmed I still get 2020 with the GMT added too.   If you are still getting empty string in the JOLT, there must be some other issue...

Comment: My template is here too:  https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/NiFi-Templates